# How can I pass an argument in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7

We are migrating to Python 3 and I want to pass a string as an argument to a class, but I'm getting the error:

```
str() argument 2 must be str, not tuple
```

```
if _python3_available():
    param_urllib = "urllib.request.FancyURLopener" # py3
else:
    param_urllib = "urllib.FancyURLopener" # py2

class SVNPicker(param_urllib):
[...]
```

I'm not sure if I can pass a string as a parameter in the class. The problem is that I need to be compatible with Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "param" needs to be the *class*, not its name:

```
if _python3_available():
    from urllib.request import FancyURLopener  # py3
else:
    from urllib import FancyURLopener  # py2


class SVNPicker(FancyURLopener):
    ...
```